# Trying to get a random number between two points and getting a divide by 0 error

Tags: c++

Hello all I have an issue I'm trying to resolve regarding the use of the random number generator.

I'm trying to set the `z axis` of a point to a random number between the two nearest points.

I was getting a `divide by zero` error, which I think I figured out why happened.
Even when I put the if statement in, it still happens sometimes.

Here is the code: (zAxis, range and min are all floats)

```
1 if (int(range) + int(min) == 0){          //this is the case where min is negative
2   zAxis = rand() % int(range);            //max is zero, which will cause error 
3   zAxis = -(zAxis / 10);
4 }
5 else{
6   zAxis = rand() % int(range) + int(min); //Getting div by 0 error here
7   zAxis = zAxis / 10;
8 }
```

I don't understand why the else clause is still executing.  I'm thinking it must be how rand() works under the hood?

Can anybody explain?

Comment: Because int(range) has to be zero at some point.  Step through your code in a debugger.

Comment: Perhaps make sure `range` is non-zero before doing this?

Comment: keep in mind that rand() % int(range) + int(min); is diffent to rand() % (int(range) + int(min));

Comment: What's the value of `range`?  Is it passed in as a parameter?  How do you know it's not zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your `if` test, it's clear you believe the random number is being modulo-ed by the sum of `int(range)` and `int(min)`.  That's not the case; the modulus operator has a higher operator precedence than the addition operator, therefore it will happen before the addition. So you're really taking the modulus of the `rand()` with `int(range)` and then adding `int(min)`.  This is almost certainly your problem.

Switch the test to check whether `int(range)` is zero and you should be on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

```
7   zAxis = rand() % int(range) + int(min); //Getting div by 0 error here
```

The issue is, modulo is the remainder of division, if (range) is 0, it will fail.

try this:

```
7   zAxis = rand() % (int(range) + int(min));
```

to fix the div by 0 answer, SO LONG AS min >= 1

Now, if you need to put it within a specific range, say 3-5 for example, it is

```
int n = rand() % (high - low) + low;
```

so,

```
rand_range(max, min)
int max;
int min;
{
    if (max - min == 0) return -1; //division by 0 would have happened
    return (rand() % (max - min) + min);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are checking for the case where int(range) + int(min) is zero, but for the modulus you are using just int(range). Here is what I think you were trying to do.

```
if (int(range) + int(min) == 0){          //this is the case where min is negative
  zAxis = rand() % int(range);            //max is zero, which will cause error 
  zAxis = -(zAxis / 10);
}
else{
  zAxis = rand() % (int(range) + int(min)); //Getting div by 0 error here
  zAxis = zAxis / 10;
}
```